# admob UnifiedNativeAd onAdFailedToLoad return Invalid template ID: -1

Tags: android, admob, unifiednativeadview

I'm working with admob native ads over 1 year.
Recently my fill rate droped from 85% to 40%.

When i checked with new sdk (firebase-ads:19.3.0) and new error handler

```
onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError)
```

most request return **Invalid template ID: -1** for `loadAdError.getMessage()`

Is anyone here experience the same issue?

Comment: I’m experiencing the same issue and have yet to find out why.

Comment: I had the same issue on emulator and resolved it by testing on real device.

Comment: same I also solved it by running app on real device.